# Multiple erros in jquery-2.1.0.min.js and browser-sync-client.1.7.1.js

Tags: jquery, node.js, gulp, browser-sync

I am running an HTML app utilising Google Web Starter Kit environment.  My environment includes:

- Node
- Gulp
- JQuery

When I start my app, running through my Node Server on Google Chrome, multiple errors occur in jquery-2.1.0.min.js and browser-sync-client.1.7.1.js.  These errors do not make sense to me and I'm thinking it's a parser bug more than a code bug.  The output of the errors are below:

- DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Element': '*,:x' is not a valid selector.
- SyntaxError: Unexpected token

I don't feel it's necessary to go into too much detail on what the bugs are as I think these are arbitrary.

Before I just throw this folder away and start again (not too much of a problem) does anyone know what could be causing this?

Thanks

Comment: I'm having the same issue. The stack trace shows it's coming from fb.setDocument. Perhaps its facebook?

Comment: @Mark Entingh Logging out of Facebook seems to have worked, if you leave this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The stack trace shows it's coming from fb.setDocument. Perhaps its facebook?

Answer (score 2):

The error message

> .DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Element': '*,:x' is not a valid selector

is a red herring. It comes from a bug in jQuery code that most likely does not affect your code.